# imagettftext PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd, imagettftext

I will generate an image with php. 
With the GD script no problem.

But I want that all the letters are superimposed (Picture).
I want to use only one input field.

```
imagettftext($image, 500,0,1000,1700, $grey, $schrift,  "$eins");
```

[image]

Comment: Draw each individual letter with a separate draw call. Stop searching/hoping for a `weird_function_that_only_one_person_in_the_universe_will_ever_use()` and learn to take the available tools and bend them to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. $letters = str_split($eins);

 foreach($letters as $item):
  imagettftext($image, 500,0,1000,1700, $grey, $schrift,  $item['age']);
 endforeach;